# Find files, grep for pattern, head the first 10 then tar those

Tags: grep, find, tar

I'm looking for a pattern in files using find, then I only want the first ten I find and tar those.

```
find /var/log/file | xargs grep "pattern" | head -n10​ | tar -czvf tarfile.tgz
```

I have also tried to `xargs` the `tar`. This too results in errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I see from the first command:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
tar cvzf files.tar.gz $(find /var/log/file -type f -exec grep -l "pattern" {} + | \
head -n10)
```

here, `grep -l` will print only files which matches pattern.

---

You would have to use `-P` option of `tar` if you are getting error like

> error tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

see `man tar`

```
-P, --absolute-names
     don't strip leading '/'s from file names
```

Or you may specify `-C` to change the directory, instead of specifying full path of the archive file.

Comment: This works. Just tested it and it created the tar. Although I did get the error tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: What if I wanted to get all files found that matched pattern not just the first 10. How would I then terminate the end of the command properly? use only -exec grep -l pattern {} + or {} \;

Comment: you would have to use `-exec grep -l pattern {} \;`

Comment: And the closing brace? Place it right next to the {} \; or leave a space or does it matter?

Comment: yes, it does matter, `{} +`  or `{} \;` there is no space between opening and closing curly brace. and after closing curly brace there is space.

Comment: I meant the parenthses, sorry. So {} \; )  or this {} \;)

Comment: no that doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

try

```
tar cvzf tarfile.tgz $(find /var/log/file | grep "pattern" | head -n10 )
```

where

- code inside `$( )` build a list of 10 files.

unlike cpio, tar will not accept a list of file in stdin.

Comment: Would there be a problem if the path included wildcards? I am still getting the same error. my actual path looks more like this -- find /var/log/*/*/file. Thats the only thing I can think of that would cause this problem

Comment: Actually I just used the exact path to rule out a wilcard issue and still getting the same error.

Comment: you shouldn't mix * and find, try `find /var/log -type f -name file`